# How to check if a given table is a valid sequence?

Tags: lua

```lua
local seq = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } -- obviously, it's a sequence.
local non_seq = { 1, 2, 3, nil, 5 } -- but it's not.
```

The defination about **sequence**: [The Length Operator](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7)

This question is in chapter 5 of Programming in Lua 4st.

Any comments I would greatly appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You linked the information you need for your answer.

A border in Lua 5.3 is defined as:

```lua
(border == 0 or t[border] ~= nil) and t[border + 1] == nil
```

A proper sequence can only contain one border. However to cover some other condition the code does require a bit more leg work, such as validating the index can be in a sequence.

```
function is_sequence(t)
    local borders = 0

    if t[1] ~= nil then -- all sequences must start at 1.
        for index in pairs(t) do
            if natural_index(index) and t[index + 1] == nil then
                borders = borders + 1
                if borders > 1 then
                  break
                end
            end
        end
    end

    return borders == 1 or valid_no_borders(t) and borders == 0
end

function natural_index(index)
    return type(index) == "number" and index > 0 and math.floor(index) == index
end

function valid_no_borders(t)
    result = true
    for k in pairs(t) do
      if natural_index(k) then
          result = false
          break
      end
    end
    
    return t[1] == nil and result
end
```

```lua
-- Tests
local seqs = {
  { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, -- obviously, it's a sequence.
  { 1, 2, 3, 4, ["potato"] = 5 }, 
  { 1, 2, [3.3] = 3 },
  { [2.2] = 2 },
  { [-1] = -1, [0] = 0, 1, 2, 3 }, 
  {},
}
for _, v in ipairs(seqs) do
    print("seq: ", is_sequence(v))
end

local non_seqs ={
    { 1, 2, 3, nil, 5 }, -- but it's not.
    { [2] = 2 },
}

for _, v in ipairs(non_seqs) do
    print("non_seq: ", is_sequence(v))
end
```

Results

```
seq:    true
seq:    true
seq:    true
seq:    true
seq:    true
seq:    true
non_seq:    false
non_seq:    false
```

---

This method has the benefit of only evaluating each element once and exiting as early as possible if the table is not a valid sequence.

---

Comment: There's a small mistake in that answer: `pairs` only iterates over keys with non-nil values, so if `[0] = nil`, it will never check the key `0`, therefore skipping an important part of the definition: the first half of `(border == 0 or t[border] ~= nil)`. This would cause a table like `{ [2] = 2 }` to falsely be considered a sequence, when it actually has two borders: 0 and 2

Comment: Oh, and I also just noticed while writing my own implementation of the definition from the manual that numbers aren't necessarily natural numbers, so a table like `{1, 2, 3, [5.4] = 'float'}` is technically still a sequence and so is `{1, 2, 3, [-4] = "negative"}`

Comment: The manual states `In words, a border is any (natural) index in a table where a non-nil value is followed by a nil value (or zero, when index 1 is nil).` specifically natural index, at least for the 5.3 manual that the OP linked. 5.4 mentioned `positive integer`

Comment: Yep. Which is why negative and fractional indices have to be ignored when strictly implementing the definition of the manual :D

Comment: Exception where a sequence can also start with minus keys: The arg table - Start Lua 5.4 with: ```lua -W -i -e "_G[1] = 1 _G[2] = 2 _G[3] = 3 _G[4] = 4 warn('Press Strg & D')" - -- /dev/null 1 2 3 4 5 6 7``` and use after following the warn() message: ```print(table.concat(arg, ' ', -5))```

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer Thanks for all the feedback, i noticed floats in my code were a nonissue as i was specifically looking for if current index + 1 was present, but negative number did need to be treated.

Comment: @Nifim `{ [-1] = -1, [0] = 0, 1, 2, 3,}` is a valid sequence with exactly one border: `3`. Same goes for `{ 1, 2, [3.3] = 3}` (`2`) and `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, ["potato"] = 5}` (`4`)

Answer (score 2):

There might be a better way, but the first thing I could come up with would look something like this:

```lua
local function sequence(tab)
   local border
   for index in ipairs(tab) do
      border = index
   end
   for index in pairs(tab) do
      if type(index)=="number" and index > border then
         return false
      end
   end
end
```

The problem is that you need to iterate over the table twice; the first time up to the first border, then either until the first integer key larger than the first border, or through the entire table if it is indeed a sequence.

---

As @Nifim pointed out, you can also implement the definition directly. A slightly improved version of their answer:

```lua
local function natural(value)
   return type(value)=="number" and value >= 1 and value % 1 == 0
end
local function sequence(tab)
   -- 0 can be a border even when it's nil
   if tab[1] == nil then
      for index in pairs(tab) do
         if natural(index) then
            return false
         end
      end
   else
      local border = false
      for index in pairs(tab) do
         if natural(index) and tab[index+1]==nil then
            if border then
               return false
            else
               border = true
            end
         end
      end
   end
   return true
end
```

Comment: @Nifim Indeed I did 

Comment: if you are doing `tab[index+1]==nil` and insuring the table starts at `1` then you do not need `number==math.floor(number)`. for example `{ 1, 2, 3, [4.4] = 4 }` is invalid as `3+1` indicates a border and `4.4 + 1` indicates a border

Comment: @Nifim `4.4` is not a natural number, therefore it cannot be a border in the table. `{ 1, 2, 3, [4.4] = 4 }` is, by definition, a valid sequence as it only has one border: `3`

Comment: I see where my misunderstanding was, had to go back and read the definition of sequence again, thanks for all the back and forth.

Comment: @Nifim I was actually surprised myself about how tricky this question actually turned out to be 

Answer (score -3):

All you need to do is check if the array part of the table has any holes.

```
local function isSequence(t)
  for k in pairs(t) do
    -- Is k an integer greater than 1 whose previous value is nil?
    if
      type(k) == 'number' and k == math.floor(k) and k > 1 and t[k - 1] == nil
    then
      return false
    end
  end
  return true
end
```

If you detect an integer key greater than 1 whose previous value is nil, then the table must have at least 2 borders, making it an invalid sequence. One is somewhere between 0 and that key, and the other is somewhere after that key.